# Connecting to DB from android device with API

Tags: java, android, database, api

I need to create android app, which will interact with external Data Base (I use android studio, java)

So, I tried to get access to DB on my localhost, but it didn't work. After some research, I know, that if I want to get access to DB from any android device, I should use some server, not localhost, and create API (php).

1. Please, explain me, can I create API and get access on localhost? Or only on server?
2. There are plenty of tutorials how get access to DB from VIRTUAL android device, but I want to create an application, which will work on any REAL device, not only for devices connected to my WI-FI.
3. It will really be helpful, if you advise some tutorials. I was searching so long, but now I have nothing.

THANK YOU VERY MACH FOR EACH ANSWER!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You will need a server to access your database. Imagine that your app is running on 10 devices all over the world. If you would want those 10 devices to access the database directly they would need to know your database username and password which is very insecure.

So you need a server that knows the database login and password and if an android app talks to the server, the server can decide what is allowed and not allowed on the database (for example if your users can login in your app the server could make sure that user A cannot see the data of userB. Or if you have public data in your database the server could make sure that data is only SELECTed and no one executes a DROP TABLE command)

2. To work with real devices you will need a server (I would recommend googling for "LAMP-stack", there are a lot of helpful tutorials for that). That server knows your database password and can access the database and your clients only talk to the server not directly to the database.

If you already have a database, you don't need to configure that but tutorials for Apache and PHP (which would make up your server) can be found for example here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 0):

localhost is always localhost :)

Meaning when something on your android device wants to connect to localhost, localhost is the android device.

Also connecting from your android device directly to a database has many drawbacks, including having to set the user/and password on the code in the app and the number of users / connections that will be open.

The way you should do this is to have backend program in the middle between the app and the database.

That backend program will provide an api wich your Android app can consume, and on the other side, the backend program will interact with the database.